Same R script but different results when ran interactively vs automatically
I have an R script that processes a single-cell cds object by assigning hash barcodes to each cell. It outputs p-values, but for some reason I get different pvalues when the same exact script is ran an interactive session versus when the script is automated. It seems the p-values are inflated for 1 when the script is automated. The script is ran locally.
I read in the pvalues from the interactive session and the non-interactive session to evaluate the pvalues. This is histogram of the -log10(pvalues) when ran interactively vs automatically.


This is the portion of my script where I am getting inconsistent pvalues when ran interactive vs automatically. I tried clearing my workspace when I run the script interactively, but that didn't solve the issue.
I compared the sessionInfo() between the two methods and there were no differences between package versions. I also tried setting a seed, but that didn't resolve the problem.
Does R interpret input files or scripts differently when using an interactive session vs when it's sourced?
chisq_vs_background <- function(test_hash_matrix, hash_frequencies) {
  hash_frequencies_nz <- which(hash_frequencies > 0)
  hash_frequencies <- hash_frequencies[hash_frequencies_nz]
  pvals <- pbapply(test_hash_matrix[, hash_frequencies_nz], 1, function(x) {
    tryCatch({
      res <- chisq.test(x, p=hash_frequencies, simulate.p.value=FALSE)
      unlist(res[["p.value"]])
    }, error=function(e) {
      # 1.0
      print("error")
    })
  })
  return(pvals)
}


my guess is its your plotting code; I expect you havent set a resolution, so thats somewhat dynamic; when you work interactively the size of your plot window is considered. start by evaluating that the data is the same  / different; one you confirm the data is the same; go on to investigate the variability on how its charted.

Thanks for your suggestion. I read in the data from the interactive and non-interactive session and plotted the data so that's not part of the actual script, but that is good to keep in mind! I did evaluate the results and they are different.

thats progress then; next thing to do is to verify that identical inputs were used. i.e. test_hash_matrix, hash_frequencies  ; have the automated script saves those out at the point they are passed, so you can read them in at the same point in your interactive; and compare them

Can you please include a working example that reproduces the issue? Otherwise it's very hard to answer.

Can't see anything stochastic in your code. In addition to Nic's advice that the issue might occur earlier, maybe pbapply is buggy and try using apply instead.
